# Inkscape: Object blueprints

Tags: inkscape

In Inkscape, you can easily duplicate objects with `CTRL+D`, but each copy is separate from each other. Inspired by the class concept in object-oriented programming, is there an easy integrated way to create blueprints of objects in inkscape, where changes to the blueprint will automatically be transmitted to every instance of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cloned copies (=clones) to get it. It's in the edit menu under Edit > Clone.

Making a geometric transform (scale, rotate) to a cloned copy affects only that copy, but edits to the original affect all clones. Changing color and line type or editing nodes can be done only to the original. The clones follow.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was looking for!